# django redirect to another view with context

Tags: django, redirect, render

I have this in my view

```
def foo(request):

    context['bar'] = 'FooBar'

    return redirect('app:view')
```

is there some way to include this `context['bar']` when I redirect to `'app:view'`? My last resort and alternative would be to do use `render()` however, I do not want to define all the context variables again. Is there any other approach to this?

Comment: What about this solution: https://defcon007.medium.com/django-redirect-with-custom-context-88d256bb5c98 ? Isn't it elegantenough ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In django You can not pass parameters with redirect. Your only bet is to pass them as a part of URL.

```
def foo(request):
    
    redirect(reverse('app:view', kwargs={ 'bar': FooBar }))
```

in your html you can get them from URL.

Comment: This answer is better than the ones making use of `session`, IMO. However two things might be confusing with it: (1) setting the `context` is no longer relevant and should be removed and (2) I think that URL params cannot be set using the `kwargs` or `redirect`.

Answer (score 32):

I would use session variables in order to pass some context through a redirect. It is about the only way to do it outside of passing them as part of the url and it is the recommended django option.

```
def foo(request):
    request.session['bar'] = 'FooBar'
    return redirect('app:view')

#jinja
{{ request.session.bar }}
```

A potential pitfall was pointed out, whereas the session variable gets used incorrectly in a future request since it persists during the whole session. If this is the case you can fairly easily circumvent this problem in a future view in the situation it might be used again by adding.

```
if 'bar' in request.session:
    del request.session['bar']
```

Comment: this works fine for me. However, is this really the most practical and appropriate solution for this?

Comment: Practical yes, appropriate eh it depends upon how you are using the session variable since it persists for the entire session. It was hard to judge the appropriateness based off of the question.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what an appropriate general solution is, if this isn't it. 

If I want to pass context data to a different URL without adding args to the URL itself, what are the alternatives to session variables? 

For example, adding args to the URL doesn't seem appropriate if passing a list or dict of values.

Comment: Didn't work. My page got reloaded, but nothing happened.

Comment: This code wouldn't cause that to happen @AnonymousUser

Answer (score 5):

I was with the same problem. I would like to redirect to another page and show some message, in my case, it's a error message. To solve it, I used the django messages: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/

I did this:

```py
    def foo(request):
        message.error(request, 'bla bla bla')
        return redirect('foo_page')
```

In my template foo_page.html:

```
    {% if messages %}
       {% for message in messages %}
       <div class={{ message.tags }}>{{ message }}</div>
       {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `HttpResponseRedirect` instead

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:view', kwargs={'bar':FooBar}))
```

Comment: This would make sense if the `from django.shortcuts import redirect` answer wasn't better. This is the older way.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, and here is my solution.

I use Django messages to store my parameter.

In template I do not read it with template tag `{% for message in messages %}`, but rather do POST request to my API to check if there are any messages for me.

views.py

```py
def foo(request):
    messages.success(request, 'parameter')
    return redirect('app:view')
```

api/views.py

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
@login_required
def messageList(request):
    data = {}
    messageList = []
    storage = messages.get_messages(request)
    for message in storage:
        msgObj = makeMessage(message.message, tag=message.level_tag)
        messageList.append(msgObj['message'])
    data['messages'] = messageList
    return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

What most work for me is:

```
 next_url = '/'
 url = reverse('app:view')

 url = f'{url}?next={next_url}&'
 return redirect (url)
```