# Reverse for 'download' with arguments '({'qualities': [(0, '360p'), "Also have issue with stream" not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['download/\\Z'])';

Tags: django

It happens when I try to pass the dictionary from view to html in django

View.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from pytube import YouTube
import os

def Yt(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # url of the youtube video
        video_url = request.POST.get('url')
        # get the video
        yt = YouTube(video_url)
        # get all available streams
        streams = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4')
        # Get the qualities
        qualities = [(i,stream.resolution) for i, stream in enumerate(streams)]
        context = {
            'qualities' : qualities,
            'streams' : streams,
        }
        return redirect('download', context)
    return render(request, 'yt.html')
def Yt_det(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        streams = request.session.get('streams')
        # get the quality of video
        selected_quality = int(request.POST.get('selected_quality'))
        # download the video
        stream = streams[selected_quality]
        # name of the video
        custom_name = request.POST.get('custom_name')
        # download the video
        stream.download(filename=custom_name)
    return render(request, 'yt-det.html', {'message': 'Video downloaded successfully'})
```

Yt.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        /* Import Google Font - Poppins */
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            padding: 0 10px;
            min-height: 100vh;
            align-items: center;
            background: #3498DB;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        ::selection {
            color: #fff;
            background: #3498DB;
        }

        .wrapper {
            height: 265px;
            max-width: 410px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 7px;
            padding: 20px 25px 0;
            transition: height 0.2s ease;
            box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .wrapper.active {
            height: 530px;
        }

        header h1 {
            font-size: 21px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        header p {
            margin-top: 5px;
            color: #575757;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .wrapper .form {
            margin: 20px 0 25px;
        }

        .form :where(input, button) {
            width: 100%;
            height: 55px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            transition: 0.1s ease;
        }

        .form input {
            font-size: 18px;
            padding: 0 17px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
        }

        .form input:focus {
            box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
        }

        .form input::placeholder {
            color: #999;
        }

        .form button {
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 20px;
            font-size: 17px;
            background: #3498DB;
        }

        @media (max-width: 430px) {
            .wrapper {
                height: 255px;
                padding: 16px 20px;
            }

            .wrapper.active {
                height: 510px;
            }

            header p {
                color: #696969;
            }

            .form :where(input, button) {
                height: 52px;
            }

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" class="wrapper">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <header>
            <h1>Youtube video downloader</h1>
            <p>Paste a url of the youtube video</p>
        </header>
        <div class="form">
            <input type="text" name="url" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Enter url">
            <button>Get video details</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Yt-down.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        /* Import Google Font - Poppins */
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            padding: 0 10px;
            min-height: 100vh;
            align-items: center;
            background: #3498DB;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        ::selection {
            color: #fff;
            background: #3498DB;
        }

        .wrapper {
            height: 265px;
            max-width: 410px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 7px;
            padding: 20px 25px 0;
            transition: height 0.2s ease;
            box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .wrapper.active {
            height: 530px;
        }

        header h1 {
            font-size: 21px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        header p {
            margin-top: 5px;
            color: #575757;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .wrapper .form {
            margin: 20px 0 25px;
        }

        .form :where(input, button) {
            width: 100%;
            height: 55px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            transition: 0.1s ease;
        }

        .form input {
            font-size: 18px;
            padding: 0 17px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
        }

        .form input:focus {
            box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
        }

        .form input::placeholder {
            color: #999;
        }

        .form button {
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 20px;
            font-size: 17px;
            background: #3498DB;
        }

        @media (max-width: 430px) {
            .wrapper {
                height: 255px;
                padding: 16px 20px;
            }

            .wrapper.active {
                height: 510px;
            }

            header p {
                color: #696969;
            }

            .form :where(input, button) {
                height: 52px;
            }

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" class="wrapper">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form">
            <label for="quality">Select Quality</label>
            <select name="selected_quality" id="quality">
                {% for i, quality in qualities %}
                <option value="{{i}}">{{quality[1]}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <br>
            <label for="custom_name">Custom name for the video file</label>
            <input type="text" id="custom_name" name="custom_name">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Download">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Yt,Yt_det


urlpatterns = [
    path('', Yt ,name='Yt'),
    path('download/', Yt_det, name='download'),
]
```

I want it so that the option selecting thing shows the quality option there like it shows 360p and 720p in the select tag's option but it shows error before it happening
[Image of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U3lN.png)

I tried changing it into a normal for loop but it had same effect lol

idk what to type anymore but it asks for more details idk what to add anymore so :)

hope I get an answer:)

Comment: For which page do you get this error? For "download page" or the 1st page in your urls?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your views.py file. You can't pass context/dictionary with redirect requests. If you want to pass context/dictionary to a page with redirect you have to use django session or other methods (Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155947/django-redirect-to-another-view-with-context#:%7E:text=I%20would%20use%20session%20variables,is%20the%20recommended%20django%20option.) for info on that)

To fix this error use this code...

```
def Yt(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    # url of the youtube video
    video_url = request.POST.get('url')
    # get the video
    yt = YouTube(video_url)
    # get all available streams
    streams = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4')
    # Get the qualities
    qualities = [(i,stream.resolution) for i, stream in enumerate(streams)]
    context = {
        'qualities' : qualities,
        'streams' : streams,
    }
    return redirect('download')

return render(request, 'yt.html')
```