# How to Add additional data while redirect a page - Django

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-views

I'm working on this project using Django, here in views.py this function return all listing which are active to index.html.

```
def index(request):
    # Get all listings where active field is True
    lists = Listing.objects.filter(active=True)
    
   
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
        "lists": lists,
         # additional key and value is needed while redirecting this route from another route

       
    })
```

so it has also another routes, and this one is where I need your help

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")  
def closebid(request, list_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # get the the user
        user = request.user

        # get the item form db
        lists = Listing.objects.get(pk=list_id)

        # get it from the database 
        if not lists:
            . ..

        # check if it exist check the user have the permission user.id == listing.user.id
        if not user.id == lists.user.id:
            return HttpResponse(f"{user.username} are trying to close objects you don't own!")
        
        # Change the active field to False
        lists.active = False
        print("This objects is ", lists.active)
        
        # Remove the list from watch list where listing = closed list
        lists, user, winningbid =  get_winner(lists)
            
        # Add the winner from the db and add it to BidWinner 
        winner = BidWinner(user=user, winningbid=winningbid)
        # then add it to list
        # winner.save()
        # winner.listings.add(lists)

        # Then redirect the user to index page with message that tell that the auction is close and somebody wins

 
        return HttpResponse("Working on it")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("This method is not allowed")
```

Closedbid function takes list_id as a parameter which then used to get Listing object from Listing model after that there are couple of error checking, then get_winner, takes the lists as an argument and return 3 values as tuple.

After this process end I want to redirect the user to the index route with additional data from this page like `"message": f"This auctions is closed, {user} win the auction."` so that when after redirecting it to the index route the above data also must be included in "auctions/index.html"

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")  
def closebid(request, list_id):
   ...
   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index")) # add additional argument so that the data will be
                                                 # transferred to that page as a key and value
```

After this page redirect to index route i want to have the same effect as follows

```
def index(request):
        lists = Listing.objects.filter(active=True)
        
        return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
            "lists": lists,
            "message": f"This auctions is closed, {user} win the auction." 
            # where the latter comes from redirecting page
        
        })
```

So how can I achieve this using HttpResponseRedirect() or any other way except `request.session["message"] = f"This auctions is closed, {user} win the auction."`  because the index route doesn't work independently. I really appreciate your help..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51156032/17728810
Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Django's [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/messages/) is a good fit for your use case.

You can add the message before redirecting:

```
from django.contrib import messages
...
@login_required(login_url="/login")  
def closebid(request, list_id):
    ...
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, f"{user} won this auction.")
    # You can also use a shortcut for debug, info, success, warning, or error:
    # messages.info(request, "...")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
```

Then, render your messages in your template using something like this example from the docs:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

`message.tags` can be used to access the level of the message such as info, success, or error, as well as other additional tags that can be added (see docs). This is often used for adding styling classes, as demonstrated above.

Or, you can access the messages in your Python code (example from docs):

```
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages

storage = get_messages(request)
for message in storage:
    do_something_with_the_message(message)
```